# something like JPanel in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, jpanel

OK.in Java it's simple to create a class that extends JPanel and than use it in main class.for example:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel(){
public MyPanel() {
    addField();
}

private void addField() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField("Panel");
    add(field);
}}
```

and then use in it another class

```
   public class Main(){
      MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
      JFrame fr = new JFrame();
      fr.add(panel);       //something like this
   }
```

The question is what is equivalent of JPanel in android.in other words,How can I create a class which extends something(?),create for example EditText in the class and than use the class in MainActivity class to add EditTexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). The sub classes that will be useful to you are [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). But you should really use XMLs to create layouts. If you want to re use layouts you could use the `<include>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to extend classes e.g. EditText if you want to add custom behavior to EditText. What you need as follows.

```
<EditText
    layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

After that you can have a parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    layout_height="match_parent"
    layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

And then programatically add edit text to Linearlayout.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);
EditText editText = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.id.edit_text_id);
linearLayout.addView(editText);
```

Note: You can also create EditText via code but making an XML for it is much cleaner and easier.

Comment: What I mean is something like jpanel.where I add different views:EditTexts,Buttons,RadioButtons  in some ordinary,And than add this "panel" to my main layout

Comment: Yeah you could always use xml files for building a layout.